# Does the flow emits monitoring event if the event size is greater than 10 MB in IIB version 10

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

In IIB version 10 We have created a service that executes a stored procedure to get the data from database and sends the data file to an FTP server. we have enabled monitoring for the flow and created monitoring events on the FTP output node to save the payload that we are sending to the FTP server.

message flow executes successfully but the monitoring event on the FTP output node is not emitted in case if the payload size is greater than 10 MB . but the event is emitted fine if the payload message size is smaller.

Is there any limit on the message size for the event to be emitted or do we need to change any settings?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Check the Max Message Length of Subscription Queue.